# Couldn't find kernel 'Python 3.7.0 64-bit' that the notebook was created with

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When I loaded a Jupiter notebook in VS Code, I usually saw the message *"Connecting to Jupiter kernel: connecting to kernel"* .
Then all of a sudden VS Code stopped connecting to Jupiter server.
I installed  notebook again using `pip install notebook`

Now my Jupiter notebooks seem to work, however, I do not see  the message *"Connecting to Jupiter kernel: connecting to kernel"*
Instead, a message appears *"Couldn't find kernel 'Python 3.7.0 64-bit' that the notebook was created with. Using the current interpreter."*

It is annoying. How can I get rid of it?

**P.S.** I did not update Python itself and it is the same 3.7.0 64-bit version as before. The Python extension for VS Code is also the unchanged.
The notebook seems to run correctly, though.

Comment: Is there a way to "save" the notebook from the new interpreter?

Comment: I sorry, I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is some conflict with the initial creation of the notebook. If you save the notebook as a new file, it should clear the conflict.

You can `Save as..` by using the shortcut `Cmd + Shift + S` or going to `File` and clicking `Save as..`. Once you do that, you can change the name to a new file and try opening it again.

Comment: @user136555 did it work? also do you mind upvoting too?

Comment: Running and saving same file seems to work.